# Remove year from NSDateFormatterFullStyle string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have searched for this question and didn't find a conclusive and elegant solution. Is there anyway to change the NSDateFormatterFullStyleyear to suppress year information. I'm using the code:

```
    NSString *dateDescription;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    dateDescription = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@", dateDescription);
```

The result: Wednesday, March 13, 2013

Regards,
Marcos

Comment: just substring with dateDescription = [dateDescription substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, dateDescription.length-6);

Comment: @ices_2 That won't work well if the user's locale puts the date somewhere other than the end of the string.

Comment: but the string can be different depending on the defined user locale.

Comment: [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM d"];

Comment: @ices_2 But doing that prevents the date from appearing properly for the user's current locale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is the closest you will get without lots of tricky string processing. The call to `dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:` will update the supplied template to best match the specified locale.

This assumes that the normal "Full" style gives you the weekday name, month name, and day of the month.

```
NSString *fullMinusYear = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"EEEE, MMMM dd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:fullMinusYear];
NSString *dateDescription = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: @user2384694 The same way you add the date. Simply add whatever time related format specifiers you want. If you can't figure it out, post your own question with relevant details about what you tried and what issues you are having.